# Node.js: stream remote file to file download

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get back a remote url which contains a pdf file at another domain. I need to pass this file to the user somehow through initiating file download Save As dialogue inside the client's browsers.

Answer (score 4):

```
var request = require("request");

expressjs_app.get("/file_url", function(req, res){
   request.get('remote_file_url').pipe(res);
});
```

if you are using http module and not express js then replace the 2nd part with:

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/file_url') {
     request.get('remote_file_url').pipe(res);        
  } 
});
```

Update:
With 'request' module [deprecated](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142), there are other alternatives that can be used. Below snippet is using nodejs native `https` module. Replace the `request.get` line with this:

```
var https = require('https');
https.get('remote_file_url', remote_response => remote_response.pipe(res));
```

Comment: As of Feb 2020, 'request' is no longer actively maintained.